# How to target a child of ::part atribute inside shadow DOM

Tags: css, css-selectors, web-component

I'm dealing with a new web component and the way the tags are defined has got my stuck on something.

The html looks like this:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

      <title>Chessboard Element Demo</title>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chess.js/0.11.0/chess.min.js"></script>
      <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/chessboard-element?module"></script>

      <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <script type="module">
        const board = document.querySelector('chess-board');
        const game = new Chess();
      </script>

      <style>
        chess-board::part(white) { background-color: white; }
        chess-board::part(black) { background-color: orange; }

        /* does not work */
        chess-board [part*="black"] { color: blue }
        chess-board > [part="board"] > [part*="black"] > [part*="notation"] { color: blue }
        
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-screen">
        <chess-board position="start" draggable-pieces class="w-1/2" />
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

I want to style the notation inside the black part differently than the notation inside the white part

This works for styling all notations

```
chess-board::part(notation) { background-color: #829982; }
```

This works for styling everything inside white part

```
chess-board::part(white) { background-color: #829982; }
```

But these do not work:

```
chess-board::part(white notation) { background-color: #829982; }
chess-board::part(white)::part(notation) { background-color: #829982; }
```

Anyone know if there is a syntax for targeting the part parent?

Comment: What would be the right tags? Also your suggestion does not work at all, has no effect. Tried `[part="notation"] { background-color: #829982; }`, `web-component [part="notation"] { background-color: #829982; }` and `*[part="notation"] { background-color: #829982; }`

Comment: @vesperknight: please include enough of your code in your question that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: It is native.. it's new: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part

Answer (score 0):

```css
chess-board>[part*="white"]>[part*="notation"] {
  background-color: red;
}

chess-board>[part*="black"]>[part*="notation"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<chess-board>
  <div part="square a4 white ">
    <div part="notation numeric">white</div>
  </div>
  <div part="square h1 black">
    <div part="notation alpha">black</div>
  </div>
</chess-board>
```

**EDIT:**

From  [developers.google:](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#host)
*styles defined in a shadow root are local*

```
#shadow-root
  <style>
...
```

So try to find a way to insert above regular CSS syntax into shadow element
. Find the line of code in your component files that creates shadow element and attach or edit styles tags.

[Creating shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#create)

Comment: I updated the question to include more parts.. your answer doesn't work for me, I think it's because it would only work if there was only 1 part per div but in reality there are multiple, but only white/black and notation/alpha are of importance and the other parts should be ignored

Comment: @vesperknight That is not a problem also, just use `part*="white"`. I updated the fiddle, see the explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thanks for trying.. I'm going to mark your answer as correct because I can see that your solution works, however it is not working for my use-case.. possibly because the parts are nested inside a #shadow-root ? It's for this component: https://github.com/justinfagnani/chessboard-element

Your syntax has no effect on it, but `chess-board::part(white) { background-color: #829982; }` does work

Comment: i've updated my question again with a fully working demo

Comment: @vesperknight But you dont have a notation anywhere in your demo. What exactly are you trying to achieve? And yes I see now, shadow parts styling is different: https://meowni.ca/posts/part-theme-explainer/ https://meowni.ca/posts/shadow-dom/

Comment: @vesperknight ups i see it now.

Comment: @vesperknight Yeah I dont know how to do this, i will delete the answer, nothing with CSS i tried is not working, and I tryed to fetch shadow-root elements with JS to make a function to target child but cant get it, i think its because its not defined in document it self, its from the source.